# Hibernate Criteria: Left Outer Join with restrictions on both tables

Tags: hibernate, join, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I am doing a LEFT OUTER JOIN, but I am only able to apply Restrictions on the first table. Is there a way ti apply on the second table as well?

Here is my code:

```
Criteria criteria = this.crudService
        .initializeCriteria(Applicant.class).setFetchMode("products",
              FetchMode.JOIN);.
```

This works (applicant has an applicantName property):

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("applicantName", "Markos")
```

Neither of these works (product has a productName property)

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("productName", "product1")
```

criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("products.productName", "product1") // products: the name of the property
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("Product.productName", "product1") // Product: the name of the DB table

And this is the exception I am receiving saying (if I understand correctly) that the productName property does not exist in Applicant:

```
EJB Exception: ; nested exception is: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: products.inventedName of: org.myCompany.applicant.entity.Applicant; nested exception is: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: products.inventedName of: org.myCompany.applicant.entity.Applicant
```

I tried to use an alias, but this generated an INNER JOIN, instead of the LEFT OUTER JOIN I want.

How can I apply restrictions on both tables?

**UPDATE:**

Issue is probably the same as this:
https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2393694

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can specify left outer join in the createalias...

```
.CreateAlias("products", "p", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
.Add(Restrictions.Eq("p.inventedName", inventedName));
```

Be aware that you are doing a left outer join with a restriction on that column...essentially making it an inner join. If you also want applicants without products then you'll have to check for null product too.

Answer (score 1):

Update:

```
.CreateAlias("products", "p", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
.Add(Restrictions.Eq("p.inventedName", inventedName));
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this my problem creating a new criteria and I could use LEFT_OUTER_JOIN in both cases.