# How to create Criteria on field that can be null?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have to create create **Criteria** or **Criterion** on specific field **myProperity** (on class **MyClass**). I have to choose all objects that have **prop = null** or satisfy **specific Criteria**. So I should make something like:

```
Criteria criteria = this.sessionManager.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(MyClass.class);

specificCriteria = criteria.createCriteria('myProperity');
/* definition of specificCriteria */

Disjunction disjunction = Restrictions.disjunction();
disjunction.add(Restrictions.isNull('myProperity'));
disjunction.add(specificCriteria);

criteria.add(disjunction);
```

The problem is caused be the facts:

1. I can't add Criteria to Disjunction (to Disjunction  can be added only a Criterion), so line: disjunction.add(specificCriteria); is wrong
2. I can't somehow modify the specificCriteria, to accept null because I can't make criteria on null. (It gives me NullPointerException)

Have you any Idea how to deal with it?

Comment: A disjunction is a criterion, so you can add it to a criteria.

Comment: Yes, I have missed a line:
criteria.add(disjunction);
but it is not the case.

Comment: the problem is that i can't add Criteria do disjunction:  disjunction.add(specificCriteria);

Answer (score 10):

You can get answer of all question here
this will help you

for ex if your MyClass like

```
class MyClass{
   private long id;
   private String myProperity;
   .
   .
   .
   setter & getter
}
```

here you null issue is solved and this'll oring with other criterias.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(MyClass.class);

Disjunction disjunction = Restrictions.disjunction();
disjunction.add(Restrictions.isNull("myProperity"));

criteria.add(disjunction);

criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", value));
```

Answer (score 7):

Just for anyone else with this question. I had a similar issue where I wanted to check if an associated collection was empty and if not restrict by ID. To achieve this, the following helped me (updated code for newer version of hibernate):

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(StaffMember.class);
criteria.createAlias("franchises", "franchises", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
        .add(Restrictions.or(
                Restrictions.isEmpty("franchises"),
                Restrictions.in("franchises.id", allowedFranchises)));
```

So this allows the following:

1. staff members with no franchises
2. staff members who are in a franchise with an ID from allowedFranchises collection

Answer (score 6):

Something like this helped me:

```
final Criteria c = session.createCriteria(House.class)
    // Houses may not have doors.
    .createAlias("door", "door", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
    // Door may be null, but if it isn't it must be blue.
    .add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.isNull("door"), Restrictions.eq("door.color", "blue")));
```

This answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2208458

Comment: This is the answer to use for Hibernate 3, CriteriaSpecification exists where as JoinType does not.

Answer (score 3):

Check if value provided in `criteria` is `null` by check `isNull` and apply to your `criteria` as following

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.isNull("parentId"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Restrictions.eqOrIsNull(propertyName, value) method can be used to handle null values.